# Blender Shading Viewport Completely Grey

Tags: 3d-view, shaders, toon-shading, clipping

I was working on a project when i tried to change my clip start/end because the procedural clouds i was making didn't show anymore after scaling (quite large).
Suddenly my viewport (only in shading tab) turned completely grey.
I've tried different render engines, changing clip settings and other options suggested in similar questions but none work.

Viewports in all other tabs are fine. If i create a new viewport in the shading tab it's grey aswell.
I changed the sampling too, no changes. I am just getting into blender properly, try to figure out most stuff myself but i'm stuck on this one and also don't have a recovery file that fixes it.

Thanks in advance for all help; much appreciated :)

(I'm on Blender 3.4.1 Running on an older Mac PC - Yes,the metal box ones)